# Select2 with ajax gets initialized several times with Rails turbolinks events

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am a developing a Ruby On Rails app using Rails 4.2.6. I am using Turbolinks alongside jquery.turbolinks (sorry I could'nt post the links to those elements as I am a newbie on the site). My problem is very simple but I just can't solve it. Here it is:
I have a form fetched through AJAX

```
<div class="card-footer">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline" data-remote="true"  href="/profiles/Mke5kA/positions/new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nouvelle expérience professionnelle</a>
  <div id="new_position_form"></div>
</div>
```

The form contains Select2 elements that get their data through AJAX

```
= simple_form_for [profile, position], remote: true, html: {id: 'positionForm', class: 'm-b-1'} do |f|
  = f.input :company_id, as: :select, input_html: {:'data-behaviour' => 'company-select2', :'data-kind' => 'company'}
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :summary
  - location = f.object.build_location
  = f.simple_fields_for :location do |l|
    = render 'locations/fields', l: l, city: position.city
  = render "profiles/shared/date_fields", f: f, model: position
  = f.input :skill_list, as: :select, input_html: {multiple: true, :data => {:behaviour => 'acts-as-taggable', :'taggable-context' => 'skills'}}
  %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"}= icon('check-square-o', 'Enregistrer')
  = link_to icon('remove', 'Annuler'), 'javascript:void(0)', 
        data: {:'lgnk-behaviour' => "remove-form", :'lgnk-target' => "#positionForm" }, class: 'btn btn-secondary'
```

- The Select2 elements are "activated" currently upon Rails Trubolinks events "page:load page:update", but I have also tried "page:change"
- When the form is fetched: the select2 elements are fine (activated correctly):

[image: Initial form (after AJAX fetch]

My problem appears when I try typing in the Select2 that are using AJAX to get the data: all the select2s are duplicated:

[image]

Here is how I get the Select2 initialized:

```
var loc_tag = function() {
  $('[data-behaviour="acts-as-taggable"]').not('.select2-hidden-accessible').each (function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).data('value')) {
      var options = $(element).data('value').split(', ');
      $.each(options, function(key, tag){
        $(element).append($('<option selected></option>').val(tag).text(tag));
      });
    }

    $(element).select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "/tags?context="+$(element).data('taggable-context'),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json"
        },
       delay: 250,
       data: function (params) {
         return {
           q: params.term, // search term
           page: params.page
         };
       },
       processResults: function (data, page) {
         return {
           results: data
         };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: true,
    language: "fr",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    width: "100%",
    placeholder: 'Mots clés...'
    });
  });

};
$(document).on('page:load page:update', loc_tag);
```

I want the Select2 elements to get initialized only once (when the form is fetched) and not upon AJAX responses on them getting their data. I have tried jQuery.not(".select2-hiden-accessible") on the elements unsing Select2 (select2-hidden-accessible being the class Select2 adds to an initialized Select2 element) but it does not work.

Many thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 42):

When using Turbolinks 5 and select2, the `select2` object is no longer attached (see below for test) to the `<select>` when using the back button to return to a page. A new `select2` object is created and attached after going back but it was unusable.

jack's answer didn't work for me because when the new `select2` object is added, the `<select>` still has **`class='select2-hidden-accessible'`** which, among other things, sets `width: 1px !important`. When the new `select2` object is created it's basically invisible.

The key for me was to **destroy all select2 objects before TL caches the page**. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
  $('.select2-input').select2('destroy');
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.select2-input').select2();
});
```

### More Detail

I believe this is the correct approach given the [Turbolinks documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#preparing-the-page-to-be-cached) (emphasis mine):

> ### Preparing the Page to be Cached
>
> Listen for the turbolinks:before-cache event if you need to prepare
>   the document before Turbolinks caches it. You can use this event to
>   reset forms, collapse expanded UI elements, **or tear down any
>   third-party widgets** so the page is ready to be displayed again.

### Testing `select2` Existance

To test if the `select2` object is attached to the `<select>` you can execute the following in the console:

```
('.select2-input').first().data('select2')
```

Comment: works for me!, thanks. And it's more elegant than Jack's one

Comment: You can destroy all select2 select with: `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {
  $('.select2-hidden-accessible').select2('destroy');
});`

Comment: @Pioz solution avoids an extra step of checking, works well.

Comment: @Pioz you solution works but need to add `if($('.select2-input').first().data('select2'))` condition to check that destroy only if `select2` is attached to that input

Answer (score 6):

**2021 UPDATE**:

Using the `turbolinks:before-cache`:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
  // removing the select2 from all selects
  $("select").select2('destroy');
});
```

And loading the select2 when `turbolinks:load`:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  // applying select2 to all selects
  $("select").select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4' // if you want to pass some custom config
  });
});
```

Of course, you can create a custom `.select2-binder` class or a `data-select2-binder` to choose which select will be affected.

---

I had the same issue and I solved by doing:

```
// init.js (you can pass an container instead of using document

$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $( document ).find('select').not('.select2-hidden-accessible').select2();
});
```

And now I don't have those duplicated selects :)

Comment: This indeed does not lead to duplicated selects, but when using the 'back' button to got back to a page with a select2 box the selectbox can no longer be selected. @jack's is a bit less elegant but the more proper solution here.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and I found that when you press the back button both the `select` and the `select2` elements are rendered but they are not bound together so when you re-initialize it with `$('select).select2()` it creates another brand new `select2` element next to it.

So here's what I did before initializing the select2:

If the `select` is not a `select2` (i.e. `$(el).data('select2') == undefined`) but there is already a `select2` element next to it, then remove it.

```
if ($(el).data('select2') == undefined && $(el).next().hasClass('select2-container')) {
  $(el).next().remove();
}
$(el).select2();
```

Comment: I feel like it really should be [addressed upstream](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails/issues/47).

Answer (score 2):

### Note for rails 7 and select2.js users.

In rails 7 version turbo-links deprecated. New library's name is turbo.
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive
You can add the tag below to html's head section to prevent caching. So select2.js can work properly now.
[Documentation](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#ensuring-specific-pages-trigger-a-full-reload)

```
<meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload">
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here worked for me.

I was able to get around this altogether by not caching the page with the select.

I use this on the top of the page with select: `<% provide(:no_cache, true) %>`

I use this on `application.html.erb`:

```
<% if yield(:no_cache) %>
  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. There is no duplication even though click on backward, forward or click other links and comeback to the page where the select2 was initialized.

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('.select2-container').remove() // this will remove all the select2 containers
  $('.select2-input').select2(); // and this will reinit the select2 again
})
```

### Update

I see some good advices [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/102) you can choose one of those. I chose to move all the javascript in the  tag instead of put them in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

## Rails 7 Update With Cache

*Originally written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77781353/10249627)*

Many things here won't work in Rails 7 especially `turbolinks:before-cache` event. New event that you are looking for is `turbo:before-cache`, and `turbo:load` so it would look like this:

```js
$(document).on("turbo:before-cache", function() {
    $("#select_id").select2('destroy');
});

$(document).on('turbo:load', function() {
    $('#select_id').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a same situation with my Select2 where only the first dropdown is functional, while the duplicated dropdowns created during forward and backward browser navigation are not working. To address this issue, I've opted to remove all additional dropdowns, keeping only the first one. I've then utilized the 'popstate' event.

The popstate event of the Window interface is triggered when the active history entry changes during user navigation through the session history. This event adjusts the current history entry to match the last page the user visited, or, if applicable, the history entry.

This will remove the duplicated dropdown while keeping the original one.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
   $('.select2-container:not(:first)').remove();
   });
```