# Forms with Select2 are duplicated when clicking back button on browser in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

#### _header.html.erb (for forms part)

```
<%= form_for home_path, class: 'home', role: 'search', method: :get do |f| %>
<div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
 <div class="input-group input-group-md">
 <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: ... ,class: 'form-control hideOverflow', type: "search" %>
 <%= select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(...),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control hideOverflow', type: "search" %>
 <%if logged_in? %>
  <%= select_tag "location", options_for_select([...], ...),class: 'form-control hideOverflow', type: "search" %>
 <% else %>
  <%= select_tag "location", options_for_select([...], ...),class: 'form-control hideOverflow', include_blank: true, type: "search" %>
 <% end %>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn-transparent"%></span>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

#### JS codes

```
<script>
 $( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('select#category').select2({ 
        width: '60%', 
        dropdownAutoWidth : true, 
        placeholder: "Choose a category",
        maximumSelectionLength: 3
    }); 
    $('select#location').select2({
        width: '40%', 
        dropdownAutoWidth : true, 
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
    });
 });

</script>
```

#### Glitch or rendering issues (click links to view the images)

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTXXh.png)

[after I click back button from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmdOi.png)

Can someone help me out why? Plus, my search forms are in the navigation bar in header partial file.

If I get rid of $(...).select in the script, everything works fine... I think there is a problem with select.js

Comment: I've used select2 before and never got this problem. Looks more like a rendering issue. I don't think you should worry about what users see if they press the back button after  a form submission. There's always unwanted side effects after that. Does it happen even when you don't submit the form?

Comment: @NickRameau sup buddy! It does not happened when I submit the form... What I meant is whenever you click browser's back button (the forms will be in the header always, meaning it will be in every view), they are duplicated and looked like the picture in my post... I think it bothers a bit on UX...

Comment: I think turbolinks is the problem. I have problem with datatable, select2 and a datepicker js plugins. This happen with rails 5.

Comment: @inye yeah...true :( thats what I was suspecting... Any suggestions how I should go around with Turbolinks?? Need help...

Comment: My last thought was do some like check if exist element (select2, datatable, etc) before create, `if` not exist -> create `else` -> do nothing. But I still do not try that solution. friday maybe I will try this.

Comment: @inye thank you so much! I look forward to it :D

Comment: If you try soon, tell me about

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 with ajax gets initialized several times with Rails turbolinks events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497723/select2-with-ajax-gets-initialized-several-times-with-rails-turbolinks-events)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915129/5758027

I have use this solution in my own code:

```
    $(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {     // this approach corrects the select 2 to be duplicated when clicking the back button.
        $('.select-select2').select2('destroy');
        $('.select-search-select2').select2('destroy');
    } );
```

and an observer:

```
    $(document).ready( ready );                  //... once document ready
    $(document).ajaxComplete( ready );           //... once ajax is complete
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready );   //... once a link is clicked

    function ready() {
        $(".select-search-select2").select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            language: 'es',
            allowClear: true
        });

        $(".select-select2").select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            language: 'es',
            minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
            allowClear: true
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

isn't clearing the cache all the time makes using turbolinks practically pointless?

how about something like this instead?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function(e) {
  return $('.form-control.select2').each(function() {
    return $(this).select2('destroy');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to solve this rendering issue (still waiting for the correct answer!) but if anyone has a similar problem like me, try thinking outside of box. Here is my hack: I added a back button in my applicaiton.

#### Get the full url path

```
# get the previous url 
def save_previous_page
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

#### Show the back button only if the page is NOT home page or search page

```
<% if session[:return_to] != request.fullpath%>
   <%= link_to session.delete(:return_to) || request.fullpath, class: 'back-button' do%>
     <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Meanwhile, I am still waiting and trying to fix rendering issue...

### FIXED THE ISSUE

Simply add this code in your .js file

```
Turbolinks.clearCache();
```

Comment: you add this line in application.js ?

Comment: @Stephen `Turbolinks.clearCache();` is not a perfect solution because it won't retain state of the previous pages, In my case same problem with data tables and adding `Turbolinks.clearCache();` fix the problem but when i go back it didn't retain the state of data table

Comment: @Stephen, your solutions don't work and still you selected your answer as the correct answer, those are bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to be some asset inconsistency, you should check your `app\views\layouts` folder for files with duplicated declarations of wither jQuery, jQuery UJS or Turbolinks. Check all `<script>` tags of your pages, and if you are declaring both on `layout` folder and in internal views the same scripts. If that is not the case, check for `render`, `yield` or `build` calls

Comment: ohhh... Maybe.. I will check it out and let you know :)

Comment: weird... I have not declared twice in the views though! I only did it in _header file (now moved to application.html.erb). errr... :(

Comment: If I get rid of .select extension in the script, everything works fine... I think there is a problem with select.js

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, don't run the select2 builder on stuff you would rather it not run on.

```
$("select#category:not(.select2-container):not(.select2-hidden-accessible)").select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rails 7 Update

Many things here won't work in Rails 7 especially `turbolinks:before-cache` event. New event that you are looking for is `turbo:before-cache`, and `turbo:load` so it would look like this:

```js
$(document).on("turbo:before-cache", function() {
    $("#select_id").select2('destroy');
});

$(document).on('turbo:load', function() {
    $('#select_id').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using rails 7, same issue occurred for me while using select2 along with tubrosteam.

```
$(document).on('turbo:before-cache', function (){
            select2Elements.forEach(function (selector){
                if ($(selector).data('select2')) {
                    $(selector).select2('destroy');
                }
            })
  })
```

(here select2Elements are array of id's(['#selector_1', '#selector_2',.... ]) which represents select2 field)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35757872)