# [Rails 5][Gem select 2] failed in loading js after back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, select2-rails

I am using select2 and ransack gem for multiple searching but I got a big problem.

My js file: `search.js`

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $("#q_city_matches_any").select2({
    placeholder: I18n.t("js.city")
  });
});
```

My slim: `index.html.slim`

```
p.form-group= f.select :city_matches_any, @cities, {}, {class: "form-control", multiple: true}
```

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require i18n
//= require i18n.js
//= require i18n/translations
//= require_tree .
```

Its oke in normal case but problem happens when I move from index page to other page and then click button back of browser to back to index page.

Normal case: https://gyazo.com/9ea59e58e5271cd27ff716e548f51f17

Issue: https://gyazo.com/3d8826be1b4f028760618e83e8d7b9cf

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Turn off caching for Turbolinks and check if it helps: `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">`

Comment: Thank you! It really works but the performance is too lower than before.

Comment: Yes it will be. You dont need to stay with this temporary solution'. Now you know where to look for solution. I don't know how Turbolinks cache works. Maybe you will find some event `after-cache-fetch` and then it will be possible to reinit your widget.

Comment: @Mkay1 Thank you so much! I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I sovled my problem

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function(){
  $("#q_city_matches_any").select2("destroy");
});
```

Refer: [Select2 with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497723/select2-with-ajax-gets-initialized-several-times-with-rails-turbolinks-events)